# How can I declare a struct, and initialize, when I don't know from the outset how large the input file will be?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that takes data from an input file and loads a structure of up to 100 items. Although my sample data input file has info for 5 friends in it, I think the program should be capable of more or less depending on the input data file fed to it. How can I declare struct friends, and initialize, when I don't know from the outset how large the data file will be?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


    /* A Structure used to hold dates */
    /* ------------------------------ */
    struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

struct name
{
    char    last_name[15];
    char    first_name[10];
    char    middle_initial;
};



/* A Structure used to hold friends' information */
/* it uses the previous structures as well. */
/* ------------------------------------------- */
struct info
{
    struct name sname;
    char address[20];
    char city[15];
    char state[3];
    long zip_code;
    struct date sdate;
};




/* The main program itself */
/* ------------------------ */

int main()
{
    /* Variable and Structure Declarations */
    /*------------------------------------ */


    struct info friends[5]{};

    int number = 0, b = 1, max = 12, k = 1, x = 1, d = 1, value = 0, i;
    int count = sizeof(friends) / sizeof(friends)[0];
    char c, file_name[80], sortby;
    char full_name[40], mil[] = " \0";

    FILE* in_file_ptr, * out_file_ptr;



    printf("Welcome to Jim's friends Program. \n \n");
    printf("Enter File name:   ");
    scanf("%79[^\n]", file_name);
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);  /*clears input buffer. */
    printf("You have %i friends. \n\n", count);


    in_file_ptr = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (in_file_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Cannot open file %s for reading.\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }

    out_file_ptr = fopen("report5.txt", "w");
    if (out_file_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Cannot open file report5.txt for writing.\n");
        return 1;
    }


    /* Obtain information from input data file, store in structure. */
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

    for (i = 0; !feof(in_file_ptr) && i < 100; i++)
    {

        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].sname.last_name);       /* read name  */
        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].sname.first_name);      /* read name  */
        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].sname.middle_initial);      /* read name  */
        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].address);   /* read addr  */
        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].city);      /* read city  */
        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].state);     /* read state */
        fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%d", &friends[i].zip_code);             /* read zip   */

        count++;

        /* ---------------------------------------------- */
        /* Read in either the \n after the zipcode,       */
        /* or the EOF indicator and end of input file.    */
        /* ---------------------------------------------- */

  fgetc(in_file_ptr);

    }  /* end for loop */

/* Final Report is printed out */
/* --------------------------- */

    printf("\n\n                  Jim's Friends \n");
    printf("                    ------------- \n");
    printf("Name                  Address          City           St Zip          Date");
    printf("\n");

    for (d = 0; d < count; d++)
    {
        printf("\n%s", friends[x].sname.first_name);
        printf(" %c ", friends[x].sname.middle_initial);
        printf("%s ", friends[x].sname.last_name);
        printf("%18s", friends[x].address);
        printf("      %s", friends[x].city);
        printf("      %s", friends[x].state);
        printf(" %.5d", friends[x].zip_code);
        printf("     %d/%d/%d", friends[x].sdate.month, friends[x].sdate.day, friends[x].sdate.year);
        x = x + 1;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    /* Close the data files. */
    /* --------------------- */

    fclose(in_file_ptr);
    fclose(out_file_ptr);
    
    return 0;
} /*end main*/
```

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation - ie `malloc` and friends. Need to either work out how many data elements there are prior to allocation or grow the memory with `realloc` as needed or use a node based data structure such as linked list.

Comment: @Lucas Agreed. But this is clearly a learning assignment and there could be requirements/restrictions on what the solution needs to include or not include.

Comment: @kaylum Yeah there could be restrictions. Then in that case, I would strongly suggest OP to google and explore things.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  How do you expect us to reproduce the problem and help you debug it?

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use:  `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\n Cannot open file %s for reading.\n", file_name);`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error indication is from a C library function, should also output (to `stderr`)  the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  the function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n Cannot open file report5.txt for writing.\n");
        return 1;`  this code leaves a 'dangling' open file.  The code should close that open file: Suggest: `fclose( in_file_ptr );` between these two statements

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; !feof(in_file_ptr) && i < 100; i++)` and the following code block:  each of the calls to `fscanf()` should be checking the returned value (not the parameter values).  Each of those calls to `fscanf()` have just one 'format conversion specifier` so any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred and should result in exiting the loop.

Comment: regarding statements like: `fscanf(in_file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", &friends[i].sname.last_name);`  the trailing 'white space' `\n` means the function will not return until some non 'white space' character is encountered. This creates some subtle problems.  Suggest: `fscanf(in_file_ptr, " %[^\n]", &friends[i].sname.last_name);` notice the leading space which will consume any 'white space' before the data. (cont)

Comment: (cont): the length of the input field is (in this case) 15 characters and the `%[...]` input format specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input, so to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  Suggest: `fscanf(in_file_ptr, " %14[^\n]", &friends[i].sname.last_name);`   The same considerations exist for the other calls to `fscanf()`.  (cont)

Comment: (cont): Finally, with all the above considerations, the statement would become:  `if( fscanf( in_file_ptr, " %14[^\n]", &friends[i].sname.last_name) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "fscanf to read last name failed\n" ); }`

Comment: @user3629249 yeah so I didn't include the rest of my code/program from where i left off at /* Final Report is printed out here*/. But it does compile, at least it does for me. I've edited it above.

Answer (score -1):

Usually there is a maximum input size given to take into consideration. If not, and if you are constructing the input, place a counter in the beginning of the file indicating how many inputs there are (number of friends structs to read), then use malloc

Ex:

> File: 
> 3 
> first_struct...
>  second_struct...
>  third_struct...

Read the `3` into a variable: `n` for example.
Then create the `struct info *friends = malloc (n*sizeof(struct info));`
Then loop `n` times, and each time insert into the struct `n` the nth line read